# Use PHP to get values in option value

Tags: php, sql

I want to get the value of the option using PHP, and depending on the chosen option i want the page to display different results depending on what they choose.

I do not have a submit button as i want the data to change when the user clicks on an option from the drop down list.

Here is my form:

```
<form action="#" name="viewall" id="viewall" method="post">

<label for="date" id="date">Select a decade:</label>    
    <select name="date">
    <option value="all" id="all">View All</option>
    <option value="1920" id="1920">1920's</option>
    <option value="1930" id="1930">1930's</option>
    <option value="1940" id="1940">1940's</option>
    <option value="1950" id="1950">1950's</option>
    <option value="1960" id="1960">1960's</option>
    <option value="1970" id="1970">1970's</option>
    <option value="1980" id="1980">1980's</option>
    <option value="1990" id="1990">1990's</option>
    </select>
```

And i would like if the user picks 1920's that it only shows records in that decade, if the user doesn't pick anything it will automatically show all records.

I have been trying to use the following code and kind of got it working using submit button, but it would only show either 1920's or 1970's and wouldn't change.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
//sel_val stores selected value in a variable   
//mysqli_real_escape_string() function escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement.
$sel_val = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['1920']);
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM details
WHERE year < '1930' AND year > '1919' ORDER BY year ASC;");

}

elseif(isset($_POST['submit'])){
//sel_val stores selected value in a variable   
//mysqli_real_escape_string() function escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement.
$sel_val = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['1970']);
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM details
WHERE year < '1980' AND year > '1969' ORDER BY year ASC;");

}

else
{
$sel_val = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['all']);
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM details ORDER BY year ASC;") or die(mysqli_error($con));

}
```

Any suggestions with or without a submit button would help.

Comment: You will need to use Javascript to get the option value on the `change` event, and send an AJAX request to your server (i.e. PHP script) and then display the results as you see fit with Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   if (is_numeric($_POST['date']) {
       $sel_val = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['date']);
       $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM details WHERE year = " . $sel_val);
   } elseif ($_POST['date'] === 'all') {
       $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM details ORDER BY year ASC");
   }
} else {         
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM details ORDER BY year ASC;") or die(mysqli_error($con));
}
```

Comment: Yes. Jordan your mysql...php...ifs... almost everything were a bit off.... Use this code that nowy has provided and you will most likely be able to achieve what you're dong. Still research ajax as you need to understand the difference between client and server side implementations.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you only get 20's or 70's is because that is all that is coded in the case statement.  If those actually worked, you just need to code a few more conditions.  Change the date values by 10 years for each until you get all the decades.

You will need AJAX to do this without a submit. To learn more about AJAX please see [jQuery's AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or if you prefer [Javascript and Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) You can also search on the numerous posts on StackOverflow to learn what other users have gone through!

Comment: When i choose "1920's" and click submit, it shows the correct results.  But if i choose "1970's" or "view all" after that it does not work. Any ideas why? @KingOfAllTrades